# Command child process output stream

Tags: rust, stream, command

I have an Actix Web application and what I want to achieve is that making an interactive command in one of my routes.

- Run the command and stream
- Get the first data that is streamed
- Return that to the user without killing the child process, let it keep running until it exits.

Rust child process not correctly streaming the data. For example I have the below code:

```rs
let mut command_output = command
    .arg("arg1")
    .arg("arg2")
    .arg("arg3")
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();

match &mut command_output.stdout {
    _ => {
        // ...
    }

}

println!("the data {:?}", command_output.stdout);

let status = command_output.wait();
```

I want that child process to stream the data. Right now, firstly there is one text printed to terminal that says "the data None" then one other line is printed with the output that I was expecting but it's not my `println!` I don't know where does that comes from, probably that is internal but I need to access that data, it is not printed within my `println!`.

I tried to read the stdout with `BufReader` and changed `command.stdout()` to different values like inherit and piped but still streaming is not working as expected. I can't println that value, it's printed by the process internally I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to capture output from a child process, you need to call [`Command::stdout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.stdout) supplying the argument `Stdio::piped()`.

If you do not do that, the child process will inherit the same `stdout` as the parent process, and the output is displayed on the terminal instead of being captured by the parent process. In that scenario, the child's `stdout` will be `None`, which is what you are getting when you print it.

If you do call `command.stdout(Stdio::piped())` then the child's `stdout` will be `Some(stdout)` where `stdout` is an instance of [`std::process::ChildStdout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.ChildStdout.html). This struct implements the `Read` trait, so you can read from it. For example, to read line by line:

```rust
    let mut command = Command::new("ls")
        .arg("-ltr")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    let stdout = command.stdout.take().unwrap();

    let mut bufread = BufReader::new(stdout);
    let mut buf = String::new();

    while let Ok(n) = bufread.read_line(&mut buf) {
        if n > 0 {
            println!("Line: {}", buf.trim());
            buf.clear();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1bacb1ee7cb676ec4a1bfd6d8395c170)

Comment: I can capture the output now, thank you. But I already tried to add `Stdio::piped()` before and it didn't worked but i tried it without a buffer reader and read directly stdout.